# Прoблема с подключением через Ip

Tags: c#, .net

Есть такой код:

```
IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddres);
IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 9100);
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(WriterText));
client.Close();
```

ipAdress приходит из вне.
Но крашится сразу с первой строчки с ошибкой:
Socket.Exceprion "Данный хост неизвестен".
На другом устройстве у меня все настроено. И Ip и Шлюз и маска.

Comment: Что именно содержит `ipAddres`?

Comment: ipAdress содержит сам ip устройства к которому я подключаюсь(192.168.100.25)
Тип IpAdress - string

Comment: Метод Dns.GetHostEntry() может  разрешить IP-адрес в экземпляр IPHostEntry, но для этого ему нужно передать экземпляр типа IPAddress, а не string

Comment: @VadimArtyushenko https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry

Comment: @aepot, ну я вроде там и смотрел) А в чем я был не прав?

Comment: @VadimArtyushenko метод без проблем принимает `string`

Comment: @aepot, да, точно, там внутри метода входная строка проверяется на то, что это IP: 
`if (IPAddress.TryParse(hostNameOrAddress, out address))
{ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ipAdress содержит сам ip устройства к которому я подключаюсь(192.168.100.25) Тип IpAdress - string

DNS - это когда у вас URL (адрес с доменным именем хоста) есть. Задача DNS - превращать доменное имя в IP. Превращать IP в IP DNS не умеет.

```
IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddres);
// ...
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло решить проблему!